# text-anchor like property for aligning svg or g element

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have to align an `svg` or a `g` element such that it either aligns as starting from a specified coordinate or ending at that point (much like `text-anchor` for `text` element).

Yes, I can do this by `translate` property but I want it to be as simple as specifying a `start` or `end` value like it is done in the `text-anchor` property for texts.
Does such CSS property exist?

Answer (score 0):

No.  There nearest you get is maybe something like:

```
svg {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 500px;
   right: 800px;
}
```

This will work for root `<svg>` elements, but will not work for `<g>` elements.